# Get DataField value while updating row (asp GridView) asp.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView control in my `.aspx` file which is filled by my table (**Id**, **Surname**) :

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="gridView_1" 
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" <!-- used to customize my columns -->
    DataKeyNames="Id" 
    DataSourceID="sqlDataSource_1"
    OnRowUpdating="gridView_rolesTiers_RowUpdating">

    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField 
        DataField="dbColumn_db" 
        HeaderText="Id" 
        InsertVisible="False" 
        ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField 
        DataField="dbColumn_Surname" 
        HeaderText="Surname" 
        SortExpression="RLT_Intitule">
    <asp:CommandField 
        ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have an associated SqlDataSource which allow me to use a stored procedure to display my **Surnames** :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="sqlDataSource_1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConString %>"
    SelectCommand="procedure_Select_surnames"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The `GridView` control perfectly display what I want to show.

**QUESTION :** Now how can I update my rows thanks to a stored procedure without leaving the current page ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the answer to this question wasn't the one I expected, or was so complicated that it would need to change the structure of my `GridView`.

Here is a quick solution for those who search an easy way to update a row with a stored procedure :

**Step 1**

Add a [CommandField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `GridView` control to allow user to update a row. This `CommandField` has to be placed into `<Columns> <!-- here --> </Columns>` tags :

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="gridView_1" 
        runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" <!-- used to customize my columns -->
        DataKeyNames="Id" 
        DataSourceID="sqlDataSource_1"
        OnRowUpdating="gridView_rolesTiers_RowUpdating">

        <Columns>
            <!-- your precedent rows -->
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <!-- nexts attributes -->
</asp:GridView>
```

**Step 2**

Add the event handler [OnRowUpdating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which occurs when you hit the button "update" but before the user valid the update :

```
<asp:GridView 
            ID="gridView_1"
            <!-- others parameters -->
            OnRowUpdating="gridView_1_RowUpdating" />
    <!-- ... -->
</asp:GridView>
```

**Step 3**

You will now update the function we just added, `gridView_1_RowUpdating` to get the variables we need to update. Here is what the **updating stored procedure** could look like :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedProcedure_Update_Surnames]
        @id        int
    ,   @surname   varchar(50)
AS
        UPDATE     [dbo].[table_Surnames]
        SET        dbColumn_Surname = @surname
        WHERE      dbColumn_Id = @id 
RETURN 0
```

Here is the content of the `gridView_1_RowUpdating` method :

```
protected void gridView_1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string surname = e.NewValues[0].ToString(); /* NewValues is the key */

    string id = gridView_1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString(); /* get the id */

    sqlDataSource_1.UpdateCommand = "[storedProcedure_Update_Surnames] " + id + ", '" + surname +"'"; 
}
```

**Explaination :**

When your click on "update", all the field instead of the key are becoming `textBox`. These textBox contains the new (or not) value of the field you edit.

All these value are stored in an array, [NewValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)[]. You can access these data by using the index of each textBox updating (from left to right for the index order, from 0 to n).

To finish, I use the stored procedure by correctly filling the parameter with the value I need, and the line is automatically updated by triggering the behaviour of the stored procedure.

Hope it helps to those who need to perform such a process.