# Cannot push content to database from front end application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have developed a front end in visual studio that users would use to interact with a database. The only problem is the update does not work from the gridview. I have tried multiple ways to try and get this problem sorted. I have attached a picture of the table in question and the code for the gridview. Can someone please point out my error?

The error is when the update button is clicked :

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

[Database table for info read/write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoNZI.png)

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ZS_CS_EVO_IntegrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Period_Id, Evo_StockLink, Evo_ItemCode, Evo_Description, UnitRate, MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays FROM rates"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        int Period_Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        int Evo_StockLink = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string Evo_ItemCode = (row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string Evo_Description = (row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        float UnitRate = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        float MinRate = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        float RateBeforeSevenDays = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        float RateAfterSevenDays = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ZS_CS_EVO_IntegrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE rates SET Period_Id = @Period_Id, Evo_StockLink = @Evo_StockLink, Evo_ItemCode = @Evo_ItemCode, Evo_Description = @Evo_Description, UnitRate = @UnitRate, MinRate = @MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays = @RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays = @RateAfterSevenDays  WHERE Id = @Id"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period_Id", Period_Id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evo_StockLink", Evo_StockLink);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evo_ItemCode", Evo_ItemCode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evo_Description", Evo_Description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitRate", UnitRate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinRate", MinRate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RateBeforeSevenDays", RateBeforeSevenDays);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RateAfterSevenDays", RateAfterSevenDays);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" PageSize="3">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RatesLink" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ZS_CS_EVO_IntegrationConnectionString %>" 
OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [rates]" 
ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [rates] WHERE [id] = @original_id AND (([Period_Id] = @original_Period_Id) OR ([Period_Id] IS NULL AND @original_Period_Id IS NULL)) AND [Evo_StockLink] = @original_Evo_StockLink AND [Evo_ItemCode] = @original_Evo_ItemCode AND (([Evo_Description] = @original_Evo_Description) OR ([Evo_Description] IS NULL AND @original_Evo_Description IS NULL)) AND [UnitRate] = @original_UnitRate AND [MinRate] = @original_MinRate AND [RateBeforeSevenDays] = @original_RateBeforeSevenDays AND [RateAfterSevenDays] = @original_RateAfterSevenDays" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [rates] ([Period_Id], [Evo_StockLink], [Evo_ItemCode], 
[Evo_Description], [UnitRate], [MinRate], [RateBeforeSevenDays], [RateAfterSevenDays]) VALUES (@Period_Id, @Evo_StockLink, @Evo_ItemCode, @Evo_Description, @UnitRate, @MinRate, @RateBeforeSevenDays, @RateAfterSevenDays)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [rates] SET [Period_Id] = @Period_Id, [Evo_StockLink] = @Evo_StockLink, 
[Evo_ItemCode] = @Evo_ItemCode, [Evo_Description] = @Evo_Description, [UnitRate] = @UnitRate, [MinRate] = @MinRate, [RateBeforeSevenDays] = @RateBeforeSevenDays, [RateAfterSevenDays] = @RateAfterSevenDays WHERE [id] = @original_id AND (([Period_Id] = @original_Period_Id) OR ([Period_Id] IS NULL AND @original_Period_Id IS NULL)) AND [Evo_StockLink] = @original_Evo_StockLink AND [Evo_ItemCode] = @original_Evo_ItemCode AND (([Evo_Description] = @original_Evo_Description) OR ([Evo_Description] IS NULL AND @original_Evo_Description IS NULL)) AND [UnitRate] = @original_UnitRate AND [MinRate] = @original_MinRate AND [RateBeforeSevenDays] = @original_RateBeforeSevenDays AND [RateAfterSevenDays] = @original_RateAfterSevenDays">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Period_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Evo_StockLink" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Evo_ItemCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Evo_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_UnitRate" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_MinRate" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_RateBeforeSevenDays" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_RateAfterSevenDays" Type="Double" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Period_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Evo_StockLink" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Evo_ItemCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Evo_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UnitRate" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="MinRate" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RateBeforeSevenDays" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RateAfterSevenDays" Type="Double" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Period_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Evo_StockLink" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Evo_ItemCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Evo_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UnitRate" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="MinRate" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RateBeforeSevenDays" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RateAfterSevenDays" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Period_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Evo_StockLink" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Evo_ItemCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Evo_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_UnitRate" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_MinRate" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_RateBeforeSevenDays" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_RateAfterSevenDays" Type="Double" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: show us the aspx of the gridview.

Comment: Can not exactly identify the problem unless you show aspx page. But `Index was out of range` is something when you try to access the index which does not exists. Most probably it could be at `row.Cells[Index].Controls[0]` To Identify exact problem, Debug your code and check where exactly you get error.

Comment: @NK I have edited the question to include the aspx. Thank you

Comment: @SpiderCode I have edited the question to include the aspx. Thank you

Comment: You have not specified the data key names in your aspx page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not mentioned the DataKeyNames in your aspx page. However In RowUpdating, you are trying to access the value[0] of Datakey. That's why you are getting this error.

Solution:
Specify "DataKeyNames=ID" in your aspx page.

Refer [here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/212_How_to_edit_and_Delete_records_in_a_gridview_using_datakeys.aspx) for understanding DataKey concepts

Comment: Hi There, I have added in the DataKeyNames = "Id" When i ran the solution it defaulted the entire DB to Value 1 , How could I be able to update with the values the user would entire? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is because you are setting the value of each field to DataKey value which is the value of ID field in your case.That is the reason of setting everything to 1.

Comment: To rectify this, you can set the value of your fields as you have done with "Evo_ItemCode" or you can try the NewValues[] approach, refered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717301/get-datafield-value-while-updating-row-asp-gridview-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: Let me know if you got stuck again

Comment: Hi Could you please show me on one of the Int and float values how i would go about this?

Comment: Could you please tell me the value of "Evo_ItemCode". Is it also 1?

Comment: Thats correct. But my question is after you update the DB, what are you seeing in this column? Is it also 1?

Comment: Before I try to update: Id=1, Period_Id=1, Evo_StockLink=51, Evo_ItemCode=5000, Description=General, UnitRate=0.65, MinRate=180 Last 2 are 0 . After I update all go to value 1 except Evo_Description which becomes 51 the StockLink code

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Because in your code for RowUpdating, you have retreivde value of Evo_ItemCode as                                                                                                                                                                                                                             string Evo_ItemCode = (row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;

Comment: In the same way, you can retreive another fields. For example,                      Evo_StockLink = Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text);

Comment: Also, For float numbers, use this approach:                                           float UnitRate = float.parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

Comment: Does it work? As you earlier problem has been solved, please accept my answer. Let me know if you are stuck again

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Thank you for your Help, I have got the update working, mistake on my end. Your solution was spot on.